# Showing that the pmf of a complicated expression sums to 1 (i.e. it converges)

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function

### Background

For the past week, I have struggled with a complicated probability distribution in Mathematica. I want to analytically show that it is normalized, or at least, converges. This is the last part of a project in which I have finished all numerical verifications.

I have rewritten the probability distribution as nicely as I could. I would be grateful if anyone here can help me handle the 2F1 expressions. Here it is:

$$\mathrm{P}(L) = f(L)[g_1(L)+g_2(L)+g_3(L)+g_4(L)]$$
where
\begin{align*}
f(L) &= \dfrac{a^L}{(a-b)^{C}~(C-1)!~L!} \\
g_1(L) &= \dfrac{(C-1)!~L! \left(b a^C+d (a-b)^C\right)}{(a+b+d)^{L+1}} \\
g_2(L) &= \frac{d ~(C+L)! ~(a-b)^C \, _2F_1\left(L+1,C+L+1;L+2;-\frac{a+d}{a}\right)}{(L+1)~a^{L+1}} \\
g_3(L) &= -\frac{d ~(C+L)! ~(a-b)^C \, _2F_1\left(L+1,C+L+1;L+2;-\frac{a+b+d}{a}\right)}{(L+1)~a^{L+1}} \\
g_4(L) &= -\frac{b (C+L)! (a-b)^C \left(\frac{a}{a-b}\right)^{C+L+1} \, _2F_1\left(L+1,C+L+1;L+2;-\frac{a+b+d}{a-b}\right)}{(L+1)~a^{L+1}}
\end{align*}

where $a,b,d$ are positive real numbers and $C,L$ are nonnegative integers.

### Goal

1. Showing that $\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}P(L) = 1.$ If not possible, I would like to show the sum is convergent.

### Attempts

Notice the similarities between the $_2F_1$ expressions in $g_2,g_3,g_4.$ I applied some transformations on them, but was still unable to exploit them in Mathematica. Here are the transformations I tried, in all combinations:
\begin{align}
_2F_1(a,b;c;z) &= (1-z)^{c-a-b} \cdot {}_2F_1\left(c-a,c-b;c;z\right) \\
_2F_1(a,b;c;z) &= (1-z)^{-a} \cdot {}_2F_1\left(a,c-b;c;\frac{z}{(z-1)}\right) \\
_2F_1(1,b;c;z) &= (c-1)z^{1-c}(1-z)^{c-b-1}B_z\left(c-1,b-c+1\right)
\end{align}
where $B_z(a,b)$ denotes the incomplete Beta function.

Whenever I got an incomplete Beta function in the expression, however, I had $a>0$, $b<0$, and $z<-1$. This was not easy to understand.

My main issue is with $g_2,g_3,g_4$. Analytical insight would be highly appreciated. Maple or Mathematica code is also welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using (one of) the integral representation(s) of the hypergeometric function, e.g. $$
_2 F_1(a,b;c;z)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\int_0^1 dt\ t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}(1-tz)^{-a}\ ,
$$ and then exchange summation and integral?

Comment: Ah, I have not. Thanks - I will try these.